# How to pass IEnumerable<Category> as Sitecore ViewRendering model

Tags: sitecore, rendering, sitecore-mvc

Suppose you have a model class in MVC called Category (which has id and name fields)
Is there any way I can return `IEnumerable<Category>` as view rendering model to MVC view file?

Comment: What did you try and what is not working?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices to get your data to your ASP.NET MVC View in Sitecore. All of my examples below will be from the community MVC project that is available for your review. That can be found here:

https://github.com/Sitecore-Community/sample-sitecore-mvc

### View Renderings

To do what you are trying to do, having a custom model in a view rendering. You need to create a model that inherits from IRenderingModel. Using IRenderingModel requires you have a function called Initialize. In Initialize you will create the logic you need to build your `IEnumerable<Catergory>`. If you want the details of your category to be editable, you will need to make sure you return your model fields as HtmlString types.

I want to note that most developers do not use this method because it is not testable.

```
   public class Car : IRenderingModel
   {
        public HtmlString Make { get; set; }
        public HtmlString Model { get; set; }

        // Rendering represents the context rendering - this particular model is only ever used by View Renderings
        public Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering Rendering { get; set; }

        // Item represents the rendering's datasource, and PageItem represents the context page
        // These properties exist on Sitecore's own RenderingModel object
        public Item Item { get; set; }
        public Item PageItem { get; set; }

        public void Initialize(Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.Rendering rendering)
        {
            // Use the Rendering object passed in by Sitecore to set the datasource Item and context PageItem properties
            Rendering = rendering;
            Item = rendering.Item;
            PageItem = PageContext.Current.Item;

            // Set property values using FieldRenderer to ensure that the values are editable in the Page Editor
            Make = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(Item, "Make"));
            Model = new HtmlString(FieldRenderer.Render(Item, "Model"));
        }
    }
```

Then in /sitecore/layout/Models you will create a new model for your rendering. In the type field you specify the model you create above. In the example it is MVC.Data.Models.Car.

Finally in your view rendering, you specify the model class and use the Model data.

```
@model MVC.Data.Models.Car

<!-- To set the 'Background' parameter, go into the Page Editor > select 'Design' mode, click on the Featured Car component > 
    click More > click Edit component properties > Scroll down to the 'Parameters' section -->

<div class="highlight" style="background-color: #@Model.Rendering.Parameters["Background"]">
    <h3>This week's featured car</h3>    
    <p><strong>Model:</strong> @Model.Model</p>
    <p><strong>Make:</strong> @Model.Make</p>
</div>
```

### Controller Renderings

In most cases when you have custom data, I recommend using a controler rendering. It is clean, reusable and testable.

#### Model

Create a traditional model for your rendering to use.

```
namespace MVC.Data.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  This light-weight model is used as an example of how you can isolate Sitecore-dependent code into a repository, which
    ///  means your models have no dependency on Sitecore and look much more like regular ASP.NET MVC models. See DriverController.cs
    ///  for usage.
    /// </summary>
    public class Driver
    {
        public HtmlString Name { get; set; }
        public HtmlString Text { get; set; }
        public HtmlString Image { get; set; }
    }
}
```

#### View model

In the example, the author creates a View Model that has the Driver model, plus information about the rendering like the datasource item.

```
public class DriverViewModel
{
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }

    public string Background { get; set; }
    
    public Item ContextItem { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller

Then create a controller/repository to fill that model. Finally passing it to the rendering.

```
public ActionResult Featured()
{
    var repository = _driverRepository;

    var driver = repository.GetDriver();
    var driverViewModel = repository.GetDriverViewModel(driver);

    return View(driverViewModel);
}
```

#### Rendering

```
@model MVC.Data.Models.DriverViewModel

<!-- To set the 'Background' parameter, go into the Page Editor > select 'Design' mode, click on the Featured Driver component > 
    click More > click Edit component properties > Scroll down to the 'Parameters' section -->

<div class="highlight" style="background: #@Model.Background">
    <h3>This week's featured driver</h3>
    <p><strong>Name:</strong> @Model.Driver.Name</p>
    <p><strong>Description:</strong></p> @Model.Driver.Text
</div>
```